# Is ROS_PARALLEL_JOBS behaviour changed but doc not updated?

Tags: catkin-make

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The behaviour of ROS_PARALLEL_JOBS seems to be changed since it does not work setting it to or example "1". But catkin_make --help says:

```
 -j [JOBS], --jobs [JOBS]
                        Specifies the number of jobs (commands) to run
                        simultaneously. Defaults to the environment variable
                        ROS_PARALLEL_JOBS and falls back to the number of CPU
                        cores.
```

And I read that as "export ROS_PARALLEL_JOBS=1" should work.

It took me know half an hour finding out what the problem was. Maybe some better error messages would have been good.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/60007/is-ros_parallel_jobs-behaviour-changed-but-doc-not-updated?/) by [TommyP](https://answers.ros.org/users/1110/tommyp/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1339 on 2013-04-04

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The official documentation for that is at [ROS Environment Variables](http://www.ros.org/wiki/ROS/EnvironmentVariables#ROS_PARALLEL_JOBS).
This doc hasn't been changed for a long time.

You'll need to set ROS_PARALLEL_JOBS to e.g. `-j 2 -l 2`.

The reason why this pops up now is that you probably got a fixed version. Previously there was a buggy implementation following your interpretation that cast ROS_PARALLEL_JOBS to `int` and thus failed anyone that had set this correctly before.
I assume that catkin_make has been fixed but the doc hasn't been updated clearly.

**Edit:** Just checked the current catkin sources. The doc seems to be updated there. So basically that should be clear with the next release.

---

Originally posted by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) with karma: 31395 on 2013-04-04

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [TommyP](https://answers.ros.org/users/1110/tommyp/) on 2013-04-04**:
Why is the wiki page the official documentaion and how should I know that? If I would guess I would trust what the actual program says more... I solved my problem by fixing all remaining dependencies so that it worked to compiled in parallel.

**Comment by [William](https://answers.ros.org/users/10/william/) on 2013-04-04**:
@TommyP I made the `catkin_make` documentation clearer: https://github.com/ros/catkin/commit/5e89a61372d0d378a9f772d7ee5ff5820c70fd71

**Comment by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) on 2013-04-04**:
Actually the wiki page documents this environment variable for ROS - not only catkin. rosmake should also use that. The program doc should only have stated that it uses 'whatever is in there' in the first place. This was a small hickup that is fixed.